# CSS scrollable percentage div

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a div that I'd like to have a vertical scrollbar.

So far, I have used the following css, which works fine:

```
.mywrapper {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

However, I would like the div to take up as much vertical space on the page as possible. Since this is the last div on the page, I'd like it to extend all the way down to the bottom, if possible.

Comment: need a link to an example to see more clearly.

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you using? 'as much space` you are specifically telling it not to be larger than 300px in height

Comment: I realise that at the moment it will only take up 300px. I'd like to use 100% of everything from the start of the div to the bottom of the page instead.

Comment: @JonoB Than remove max-height and answer on the question about DOCTYPE. for HTML it is enough to tell `height: 100%`, for xHTML you have to tell the same thing to the html and body tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, naturally.  The body only goes as high as the content it contains.

But, a simple quick fix would be adding this to your CSS:

```
html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

---

As for extending, I've put together a quick script (using jQuery) that appears to do what you're looking for.

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/UB7uT/  (click Play)

Code:

**CSS:**

```
html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }

.mywrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function my_initialize_footer_box_absolute_height_scroller(selector) {
    var box = $(selector);
    var boxPosition = box.position();
    var boxTop = boxPosition.top;
    var boxHeight = box.height();
    var boxNewHeight = (+boxHeight) - (+boxTop);
    box.css('height', boxNewHeight+'px');
}

$(function() {
    my_initialize_footer_box_absolute_height_scroller('.mywrapper');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
    <p>some content here first.</p>
    <p>some content here first.</p>
    <p>some content here first.</p>
    <p>some content here first.</p>
    <hr>
    <div class="mywrapper">
    foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>foo<br>

    </div>
```